# Errors: Invalid JSON in tag 'schema' (Shopify Slick Sider)

Tags: json, shopify

I am building a slick slider using Shopify new feature section. All want to is add the image that has the arrow going left and right.

With a Title, Description, and Button that user can change and add the link to everything with be on top of Carousel and change with everything some click on arrow or ghost buttons at the bottom

**Here a ScreenShot.**

[image]

```
{% if section.blocks.size > 0 %}
<!-- Slick Slider Wrapper -->
<div class="carousel-wrapper" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="carousel-info">
      <!-- Title Slider Wrapper -->
      <h3>{{ section.settings.carousel_title }}</h3>
      <!-- Description Wrapper -->
      <p>{{ section.settings.carousel_product_description }}</p>
      <!-- Button Wrapper -->
      <button>{{ section.settings.carousel_button_title }}</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Slick Slider -->
    <div id="carousel-{{ section.id }}" class="carousel" data-slick='{"autoplay": {{ section.settings.carousel_autoplay }}}'>
    {% for block in section.blocks %}
        <div class="carousel-slide--{{ block.id }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }} style="width:240px">
            {% if block.settings.carousel_image != blank %}
                    <img class="carousel_image--{{ block.id }}" src="{{ block.settings.carousel_image | img_url: '240x' }}" style="max-width:240px;display:inline-block;padding:40px">
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <!-- ended of Slick Slider -->
  </div>

  </div>
  {% endif %}

  {% if section.blocks.size == 0 %}
    <div class="placeholder-noblocks">
        {{ 'homepage.onboarding.no_content' | t }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  <!-- Slick Slider Wrapper -->

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Carousel",
  "max_blocks": 8,
  "settings": [
    {
       "type":"header",
       "content":"Carousel option"
    },
    {
       "type":"text",
       "id":"carousel_title",
       "label":"Carousel title",
       "default":"Carousel main title"
    },
      "type": "text",
      "id": "carousel_title",
      "label":"Carousel title",
      "default":"Carousel main title"
    },
    {
      "type" "text",
      "id": "carousel_product_description",
      "label": "Carousel Description",
      "default: Carousel Main Description"
    },
    {
  "type": "url",
  "id": "carousel_link",
  "label": "Carousel title link"
    },
    {
       "type":"header",
       "content":"In depth carousel option"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "carousel_autoplay",
      "label": "Auto-rotate slides",
      "default": false
    },
    {
       "type":"color",
       "id":"carousel_bg",
       "label":"Carousel background",
       "default":"#fff"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "image",
      "name": "Image slide",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "carousel_image",
          "label": "Image"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "id": "slide_link",
          "label": "Slide link"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "presets": [{
    "name": "Carousel",
    "category": "Image",
    "settings": {
      "carousel_autoplay": false
    },
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "image"
      },
      {
        "type": "image"
      },
      {
        "type": "image"
      },
      {
        "type": "image"
      },
      {
        "type": "image"
      },
      {
        "type": "image"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: You should try to  validate your json. It seems like around line 9 your missing a curly brace.

Comment: @slowjack2k I validate the json file but don't know what this means.  `Error: Parse error on line 14:
...title"  },  "type": "text",  "id": "c
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'`

Comment: Your missing an open curly brace before "type"

Answer (score 0):

You were missing an open curly brace before the word type and a colon after the second type object.

```
     {
        "name": "Carousel",
        "max_blocks": 8,
        "settings": [
        {
           "type":"header",
           "content":"Carousel option"
        },
        {
           "type":"text",
           "id":"carousel_title",
           "label":"Carousel title",
           "default":"Carousel main title"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "carousel_title",
          "label":"Carousel title",
          "default":"Carousel main title"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "carousel_product_description",
          "label": "Carousel Description",
          "default: Carousel Main Description"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "id": "carousel_link",
          "label": "Carousel title link"
        },
        {
           "type":"header",
           "content":"In depth carousel option"
        },
        {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "id": "carousel_autoplay",
          "label": "Auto-rotate slides",
          "default": false
        },
        {
           "type":"color",
           "id":"carousel_bg",
           "label":"Carousel background",
           "default":"#fff"
        }
      ],
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "image",
          "name": "Image slide",
          "settings": [
            {
              "type": "image_picker",
              "id": "carousel_image",
              "label": "Image"
            },
            {
              "type": "url",
              "id": "slide_link",
              "label": "Slide link"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "presets": [{
        "name": "Carousel",
        "category": "Image",
        "settings": {
          "carousel_autoplay": false
        },
        "blocks": [
          {
            "type": "image"
          },
          {
            "type": "image"
          },
          {
            "type": "image"
          },
          {
            "type": "image"
          },
          {
            "type": "image"
          },
          {
            "type": "image"
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
```